# Items in a Repeater are lost during a postback (callback)

Tags: asp.net

Using ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms.
I have a repeater with checkboxes in it. The repeater and checkboxes have viewstate enabled. There's a button which causes a callback postback. These elements reside in a callbackpanel (similar to MS's UpdatePanel but doesn't use viewstate). The repeater is bound to a datatable during initial load and repeater shows the checkboxes. Fine so far.

During the postback (a callback), I noticed that the repeater's items' count is 0 in the page_load. Therefore I can't get any checkbox values. I can see the key/checked value entries of the checkboxes in Request.Form collection.

I think I am missing something obvious but where in the life cycle can I read the repeater's items?
Or should I get them from Request.Form?

Comment: Where do you want to read them? Show us some code.

Comment: I want to read them in page_load or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Try wiring up to LoadComplete.  All child controls are loaded recursively, so sometimes not everything you expect to be there will be present during the Load event.

2) Make sure your repeater is initialized during or prior to Init event.  If you have some code that runs to populate it, then this must be executed in Init.  During the page's lifecycle, ASP.NET tries to take the posted values and apply them to the controls.  If the controls are not created soon enough during the lifecycle, then they won't exist during that step to accept the posted values.  This is one of the more frustrating things with dynamic pages in ASP.NET, as you have to ensure the page is reconstructed during the postback in init.  So even when you see the data in the post, ASP.NET will ignore it if the controls aren't found in its collection of controls.  Also, there is some magic that happens with control IDs that it uses to map the posted values into the controls.  I don't remember the details of that though because it has been several weeks since I had to delve into the harry details.

Also, make sure you aren't doing something like using if(!IsPostBack) to initialize your repeater or other controls/data.  Even if it's a postback, you still need the controls to exist so they can accept the posted values.

I have not used a callbackpanel though, so I am unsure of how this will muddy the waters.

Answer (score 1):

**I solved my problem by overriding the `DataBind` method on the control which contains the repeater.** That prevents `DataBind`s on parent controls from trickling down and binding data to the repeater when it isn't ready for that.  My problem was that a parent control/page performed a DataBind which trickled down to the sub-controls, including the repepater, causing it to get cleared. **So you don't have to do a `DataBind` directly on the repeater on every postback like @AaronLS suggests:**

> Also, make sure you aren't doing something like using if(!IsPostBack)
>   to initialize your repeater or other controls/data. Even if it's a
>   postback, you still need the controls to exist so they can accept the
>   posted values.

All my RepeaterItems were stay present through postbacks even though I only databind once.

In my case, performing a `DataBind` on the repeater for every postback caused the form values to be reset.

Comment: Instead of overriding the DataBind on the control, why not just avoid Page.DataBind (if it is possible)? +1 for helping me!